# Typeahead is not working

Tags: typeahead.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I have this example directly from `typeahead.js` website.

http://jsfiddle.net/CNMfL/163/

It is showing `Uncaught Error: one of local, prefetch, or remote is required`. What i am missing ?

I tried by changing `source` to `local` vice-versa, as suggested in some solutions but didnt work.

Comment: What have you tried so far to fix it? When searching for the error, I get numerous StackOverflow questions regarding typeahead, with accepted answers - have you looked at any of those?

Comment: Please include the code in your question as well, not just a link to a jsfiddle. I took a quick look at the code, and it seems there is a mistake in the example. This has also been mentioned in the comments of the example on Github, and while it should have been fixed, it seems the change was rolled back. However, even with that error corrected, I still get your error as well. https://gist.github.com/jharding/9458744#gistcomment-1207722

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the HTML part:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>`

Remove the "@import url" parts